# Floating an image in the tabular environment

Tags: graphics, floats

I am trying to create a simple 2x2 question set-up for a worksheet I am creating. My problem is that I cannot get my graphic to float nicely with problem #2. I have tried various float environments and wrapping my text in different ways, but can't get it to float to where the top of the graphic is even with the text line and hangs below the text line. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\noindent {\bf Determine whether each relation is a function.}\\

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\linewidth} p{0.5\linewidth}}
1.  $\left\{(5, -7) (6, -7), (-8, -1), (0, -1)\right\}$ & 2. \includegraphics{parabola}\\
3.   $y=3x-2$ \hspace{20mm} 4.  other stuff \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: parabola]

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the `valign=t` option introduced by the `adjustbox` package there is no need for measuring:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent {\bfseries Determine whether each relation is a function.}\\

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep} p{0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
1.  $\left\{(5, -7) (6, -7), (-8, -1), (0, -1)\right\}$ & 2. \includegraphics[valign=t]{parabola}\\
3.   $y=3x-2$ &  4.  other stuff \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

As an alternative to manually adjusting the width of the columns, you could also use `tabularx` as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent {\bfseries Determine whether each relation is a function.}\\
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
1.  $\left\{(5, -7) (6, -7), (-8, -1), (0, -1)\right\}$ & 2. \includegraphics[valign=t]{parabola}\\
3.   $y=3x-2$ &  4.  other stuff \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

For an even more automated approach (at least with respect to the numbering) you might want to have a look into the `tasks` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{item-indent=2em, counter-format =tsk[1].}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent {\bfseries Determine whether each relation is a function.}\\

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task  $\left\{(5, -7) (6, -7), (-8, -1), (0, -1)\right\}$
\task  \includegraphics[valign=t]{parabola}
\task  $y=3x-2$
\task  other stuff
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\raisebox` to lower the image into position:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{Determine whether each relation is a function.}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\linewidth} p{0.5\linewidth}}
  1. $\{(5, -7) (6, -7), (-8, -1), (0, -1)\}$ & 
    2. \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+.7\normalbaselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=5em]{example-image}} \\
  3. $y = 3x - 2$ & 
    4. other stuff
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Within a `tabular`, the regular `\baselineskip` is available as `\normalbaselineskip`. So we lower the image to the baseline (so it's top sits on the baseline) via `-\height`, and then raise it back up 70% of the `\normalbaselineskip`.